# what is the first return value in the return list of opencv3 findcontours()

Tags: list, image, opencv, return-value, contour

I am trying to use opencv to get contours in an image. 
Originally, I used the following statement.

```
cons,hierarchy cv2.findContours(edges.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Then python told me that there were more than two values returned since I was using opencv3. 
So I changed the statement to:

```
im2, cons,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Then I thought im2 should contain all the image arrays of those detected contours reported in cons. 
But it happened that the lengths of im2 and cons did not match.
im2 was much shorter than cons.
I have been searching for documentation to understand what im2 actually is.
But it seems that nowhere explains what im2 is.

I will appreciate it very much if someone can give me some clues.

Thanks

Farn

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a), `im2` should be the untouched input image, as of OpenCV 3.2 and later. Earlier versions modified the input image. Check, which version you have, and you maybe find the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Really appreciate it.